# REGEX: match all numbers if a keyword exists

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex which searches for every numbers if a keyword exists in the paragraph.

For example, if my keyword is `something`, with this paragraph:

```
20
30
abc
40
def

something
```

my regex should get `20`, `30` and `40`. But for this one:

```
50
60
xyz
```

it should get nothing.

Can you guys help me out to find a good regex. Thank you so much! I'm using PCRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in single line (DOTALL) mode with a lookahead assertion:

```
(?s)\b\d+(?=.*\bsomething\b)
```

It will match numbers only when there is a word `something` ahead in input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9QaeOB/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?s)`: Enable single line mode so that dot also matches newlines
- `\b`: Match a word boundary
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?=.*\bsomething\b)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a word `something` ahead of us from current position

Comment: Work like a charm!! Thank you so much